# Aceptar sólo números

Tags: c

Quería que el programa solo aceptara números y saliera del bucle con ctrl+d. Mi solución no funciona si introduces valores no numéricos. ¿Cómo debería hacerlo o cual es el error que estoy cometiendo?

```
int main(){
int n,c,count=0;

do {
c=scanf("%d",&n);
if (c==1) count++;
}while (c!=-1);

printf("C: %d/ %d datos correctos",c,count);
}
```

Comment: La respuesta es diferente según el lenguaje que estés usando. ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]? decídete.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster c

Answer (score 1):

La función [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) devuelve la cantidad de datos leídos, si lees un número pero `scanf` no `1` es que no lo pudiste leer:

```
int valor;
if (scanf("%d", &valor) != 1)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Eso no era un numero\n");
}
```

El `while` está para vaciar el búfer para que no interfiera con futuras lecturas.